# Looking for the correct definition of the median of a discrete statistical series

Tags: statistics

I am looking for the correct definition of the median of a discrete statistical series

The following definition is widely used  : The median of a discrete statistical series is the value that divides the sorted data into **two equal parts**. When it is ordered,if the number of data points is odd, the median is the middle value and if the number of data points is even, the median is the arithmetic mean of the two middle values

For example, if we consider the series 2,2,5,5,5, according to this definition the median is 5. However, clearly the value of 5 does not divide the series into two parts of equal frequencies because there are 5 values $\leq 5$ and only 3 values $\geq 5$

Comment: An alternative definition might be that a median of your multiset $X$ is a value $m$ where $\mu(\{x \in X:x \le m\}) \ge \frac12\mu(X)$ and  $\mu(\{x \in X:x \ge m\}) \ge \frac12\mu(X)$ where $\mu$ is a suitable measure - in your case counting  with repeats.  So $m$ divides $X$ into two parts (though overlapping at $m$) where each part is at least half of the original.

Comment: but in this case the median will no longer be a measure of central tendency example 2-2-5-5-5-5-5-5-5

Comment: In that example at least half the values are $5$ or more and at least half the values are $5$ or less. So the median is clearly $5$ and my definition provides it.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for this definition